# Transforming a Dataset for Multi-Label Text Classification

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, classification, data-science, data-transform

I am conducting some experiments on multi-label classification via deep learning models.
But I face a problem with the dataset.

I use Keras,TensorFlow 2.0, numpy,pandas.

I have a dataset in the form:
[Dataset in the form that I have it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vubXF.png)

To apply multi-label classification(6 labels) I need my dataset to be in this form:
[Dataset in the form that I need it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W16ca.png)

How is it possible to achieve this? Are there any functions making this transformation easier?

Try:

```
comments_df[['abusive','hateful','offensive','disrespectful','fearful','normal']] = comments_df['sentiment'].str.split('_', -1, expand=True)
```

This gives me an error:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

Regarding the DL model I will use, it's bi-LSTM, but it doesn't have anything to do with the question per-se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to work (not optimal solution):

```
"""
Creating a column for each of the target labels with sentiment's column data.
"""


def split_sentiment_outputs(output_label, sentiment_col="sentiment"):
    comments_df[output_label] = comments_df[sentiment_col].str.split('_')


"""
Transform column's data to categorical.
"""


def transform_data_for_multilabel(output_label):
    row = comments_df[output_label]
    for index, row in row.items():
        # print("Index:", index)
        # print("length:", len(row))
        # print("content:", row)
        # print("--------------")
        z = 0
        while z < len(row):
            if row[z] == output_label:
                comments_df.at[index, output_label] = 1
                break
            else:
                comments_df.at[index, output_label] = 0
            z = z + 1

# Applying Data Transformation
output_labels = ["abusive", "hateful", "offensive", "disrespectful", "fearful", "normal"]
for i in range(MAX_OUT):
    split_sentiment_outputs(output_labels[i])

for i in range(MAX_OUT):
    transform_data_for_multilabel(output_labels[i])
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I believe that if someone opens the images I have linked then the code becomes pretty straightforward. What do you think I must clarify? Since I am a new member, your guidance would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(data = df, columns = ['sentiment'])
```

Comment: Yes, this partially solves the problem. It creates more columns than needed cause of the nature of the data, but with your code and some "dropping" of columns after it. Does the trick.